# Clean headers before pivot_longer

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset with `40` sensors with odd names (e.g. `A_B_Loc_1`). I need to convert these data to long format to plot them. I need to split the names so I know the sensor name (e.g. from `A_B_Loc_1, name=AB`) and the sensor location (e.g. from `A_B_Loc_1, location=1`).

```
require(dplyr)
require(janitor)
require(tidyfast)
require(tidyr)

df<-data.frame(time=c("2021-02-27 22:06:20","2021-02-27 23:06:20"),A_Loc_1=c(500,600),A_Loc_2=c(500,600),A_B_Loc_1=c(500,600),A_B_Loc_2=c(500,600),B_Loc_1=c(500,600),B_3=c(500,600))
```

It's about 50 million rows, so it's very slow:

**EDIT: Ouch! Some names don't have "Loc" (e.g. B_3 is sensor B, location 3).**

#**Pivoting it:**

```
df %>% 
   tidyfast::dt_pivot_longer( #tidyfast package uses data.table instead of tidyr, so much faster
     cols = -time,
     names_to = "name",
     values_to = "value"
  ) %>% drop_na()->df
```

#**Split the names**

```
df %>% 
  separate(name, 
           into = c("sensor", "location"), 
           sep = "(?=[0-9])"
           ) %>% 
  mutate(sensor=janitor::make_clean_names(sensor, case = "big_camel"))
```

Can this be sped up? A `left join` with a lookup table that adds columns based on sensor names?

Comment: `make_clean_names` does exactly the same thing many times after `pivot_longer`. I would do this before `pivot_longer` to speed things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We experimented with a few approaches to splitting columns by regular expressions. `separate` was very slow, but the fastest seems to be `stringr::str_split(..., simplify=TRUE)` to make new columns (for a tibble):

```r
require(dplyr)
require(janitor)
require(tidyr)
require(stringr)

df <-
  data.frame(
    time = c("2021-02-27 22:06:20", "2021-02-27 23:06:20"),
    A_Loc_1 = c(500, 600),
    A_Loc_2 = c(500, 600),
    A_B_Loc_1 = c(500, 600),
    A_B_Loc_2 = c(500, 600),
    B_Loc_1 = c(500, 600)
  )

df1 <- df %>%
  # Suggestion from above about cleaning names first?
  clean_names(case = "big_camel") %>%
  tidyfast::dt_pivot_longer(
    cols = -Time,
    names_to = "name",
    values_to = "value") %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  as_tibble

df1[c("sensor", "location")] <-
  str_split(df1$name, "Loc", simplify = TRUE)
```

This is presuming your biggest time guzzler is the separating columns part!

## Edit

There are at least four ways of splitting, and depending on the complexity of the split it might be quicker to use other methods (such as `data.table::tstrsplit`), but some of these would require a consistent 'split' across all rows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)


# a sample of 100,000 pivoted rows
n <- 1e5

df  <-  data.frame(condition = c(rep("ABLoc1", times = n),
                                 rep("ABLoc2", times = n),
                                 rep("ACLoc1", times = n),
                                 rep("ACLoc2", times = n),
                                 rep("AALoc4", times = n)))


(speeds <- bench::mark(
  separate = {
    df_sep <- df %>%
      separate(condition,sep = "Loc", into = c("part1", "part2"), remove = FALSE)
  },
  dt = {
    df_dt <- data.table::data.table(df)
    df_dt <-
      df_dt[, c("part1" , "part2") := tstrsplit(condition, split = "Loc", fixed = TRUE)] 
    
    
  },
  stringr = {
    
    df_str <- df
    df_str[c("part1", "part2")] <- str_split(df_str$condition, "Loc", simplify = TRUE)
    
  },
  
  gsub = {
      df_vec <- df
      df_vec$part1 <- gsub("(^.*)Loc.*", "\\1",  df$condition)
      df_vec$part2 <- gsub(".*Loc(.*$)", "\\1",  df$condition)
  },
  iterations = 10,
  check = FALSE
))


#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 separate      4.63s    5.19s     0.191    3.89GB    4.25 
#> 2 dt          99.44ms 112.32ms     8.95    28.91MB    0.895
#> 3 stringr    296.11ms  306.5ms     3.16    59.53MB    0.632
#> 4 gsub       502.85ms 528.69ms     1.63     7.63MB    0.163


plot(speeds, type = "beeswarm")
```

Plotting speeds of each approach (to iterate over 100,000 rows):

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. What happens if there's no "Loc" in the name? I'm sorry, I've just seen that some of the names don't have Loc but just A_B_1 or B_2 for example. The number is always present though.

Comment: Ah then I think your separator above (`(?=[0-9])`) might work best?

Comment: seperate might be slower but NOT that slow ;) and your sample dataset did not allocate so much memory. In your seperate example you include false garbace collection taking over 4.25 seconds. It is not fair to punish that method by cleaning up your own R memory (prior to testing). Another note, for data.table method it is not fair to include the conversion to a data.table nor is it necessary to reassign dt as dt gets updated by reference.

Comment: Very true! this was a rather quick and dirty comparison to try and compare the times that we were noticing with 1m+ row datasets. It has made me realise the relative usefulness of `data.table` though :)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dt <- melt(df, id.vars = c("time"))
dt[, c("name", "location") := tstrsplit(str_replace_all(variable, "_", ""), "Loc")]

dt
#                    time  variable value name location
#  1: 2021-02-27 22:06:20   A_Loc_1   500    A        1
#  2: 2021-02-27 23:06:20   A_Loc_1   600    A        1
#  3: 2021-02-27 22:06:20   A_Loc_2   500    A        2
#  4: 2021-02-27 23:06:20   A_Loc_2   600    A        2
#  5: 2021-02-27 22:06:20 A_B_Loc_1   500   AB        1
#  6: 2021-02-27 23:06:20 A_B_Loc_1   600   AB        1
#  7: 2021-02-27 22:06:20 A_B_Loc_2   500   AB        2
#  8: 2021-02-27 23:06:20 A_B_Loc_2   600   AB        2
#  9: 2021-02-27 22:06:20   B_Loc_1   500    B        1
# 10: 2021-02-27 23:06:20   B_Loc_1   600    B        1
```

**Edit:** OP mentions that Loc is not always present, so we split on the last underscore to get the number. Then we clean the name in the second step to remove the underscores and - if present - "Loc"

```
dt <- melt(df, id.vars = c("time"))
dt[, c("name", "location") := tstrsplit(variable, "_(?!.*_)", perl = T)]
dt[, name := str_replace_all(name, "_|Loc", "")]
```

Comment: `tstrsplit(variable, "_Loc_")` may be better

Comment: Then your names still end up with A_B, the splitting all depends on how robust the column names are though, as OP mentions in another comment Loc suddenly is not present always. I picked the easy way based on the presence of Loc to remove first all underscores.

Comment: Aha, you are right.